# Understanding LSTMs - layers data dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am not understanding how LSTM layers are fed with data.

LSTM layers requires three dimensions `(x,y,z)`.

I do have a dataset of time series: 2900 rows in total, which should conceptually divided into groups of 23 consecutive rows where each row is described by 178 features.
Conceptually every 23 rows I have a new sequence 23 rows long regarding a new patient.

Are the following statements right?

- `x` *samples* = # of bunches of sequences 23 rows long - namely `len(dataframe)/23`
- `y` *time steps* = length of the each sequence - by domain assumption 23 here.
- `z` *feature size* = # of columns for each row - 178 in this case.

Therefore `x*y = "# of rows in the dataset"`

Assuming this is correct, what's a *batch size* while training a model in this case?

Might be the number of samples considered in an epoch while training?

Therefore by having `x`(# of samples) equal to 200, it makes no sense to set a `batch_size` greater than 200, because that's my upper limit - I don't have more data to train on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your description as saying that your total dataset is of 2900 data samples. Where each data sample has 23 time slots, each with a vector of 178 dimensions.

If that the case the input_shape for your model should be defined as (23, 178). The batch size is simple the number of samples (out of the 2900) that will be used for a training / test / prediction run.

Try the following:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(23,178)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
model.summary()

print model.input
```

This is just a simplistic model that outputs a single 64-wide vector for each sample. You will see that the expected model.input is:

```
Tensor("lstm_3_input:0", shape=(?, 23, 178), dtype=float32)
```

The batch_size is unset in the input shape which means that the model can be used to train / predict batches of different sizes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My total dataset has 2900 data samples, but I was not meaning that each sample has 23 time slots. Every 23 seconds the data registered come from a different patients. So totally I have 2900/23 bunches.

Last thing: could you please explain me if I would choose a batch_size=32 what is the effect on learning?
How is effectively learning the LSTM? The sequences of 23 datapoints are broken?

Comment: I think I would need a bit more context to fully understand the scenario. You are asking specifically about an LSTM node; LSTMs are used to process sequences of data points that are related to the same label. E.g. if you are trying to do sentiment prediction such that "I'm felling great" results in the class "positive" and "Live sucks" results in the class "negative" then one would use an LSTM where each time slice is a word. Perhaps you want to elaborate on what you are trying to predict. Is the data among patients related ? What are your output labels ?

Comment: Thanks for your gentle patience. I am building an LSTM autoencoder in order to  learn the pattern of healthy patients based on a multi variate dataset of timeseries of different patients. For each patient I have 23 datapoints(rows), for this reason I want to perform training on groups of sequence which length is 23. In total I should have 2900/23 patients(126.06 patients, I have to figure out where does it come from the two excessive rows but this is out of this concern). Please don't hesitate to tell me if I am still not clear with the context.

Comment: Batch size will be the number of patiences/samples/bunches_of_23_time_slots trained together in each forward and backpropagation pass. This is not a big deal.

Comment: If for each patient you have 23 observations (each with 178 values) and then you can assign probability of it being healthy then the example LSTM above should work. You need to then add a extra Dense node with a dimension of 1 that would be your 'probability of being healthy'.

Comment: Thanks @DanielMöller - now I am sure.

Comment: Thanks @PedroMarques - I understand that behaviour, I could use it in the future but so far I am trying to just perform an autoencoder. Would you have a suggest in such direction? In case could you please look at [my specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925207/lstm-gru-autoencoder-convergency) ?